# Differences Between Hugs, Yhc and GHCi

Tags: haskell, comparison, interpreter, ghci, hugs

There are differences between Hugs, Yhc and GHCi? If there are differences, What are they?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **Update**: Hugs is unmaintained.

They are all just different implementations. I would try and explain the differences but [this article](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Implementations) does a much better job.

Answer (score 14):

First: you want GHC/GHCi. And you want it via [the Haskell Platform](http://haskell.org/platform). Then, for more info on the other implementations of Haskell, read Bartek's link.

Comment: Unless you're using any version of Mac OS X besides 10.5, in which case the default GHC/Haskell Platform install doesn't work right.

Comment: @Chuck This is giving me all kinds of grief after a recent update to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion. Is the only solution to go with Hugs until the developers of GHC decide to support 10.8 properly?

Comment: As of Sep 2012, GHC [works just fine with Mountain Lion](https://plus.google.com/u/0/111539170343022224273/posts/4uczfdzfTCb), you just need to upgrade XCode.

Answer (score 6):

Usually people use Hugs for small, testing-type prototypes (analogously to how Ruby users would use irb and Python users would use the interpreter), but for actual shipping code, GHC is by far the most popular target (analogous to how Python users would compile import modules to cpython).

They're all pretty much standards-compliant, its a matter of speed of performance vs speed of compilation.

(Dunno much about Yhc)

Comment: GHCi has a better REPL than Hugs nowadays, BTW.

Answer (score 6):

These days people kind of converge to using GHC, as it's the de facto standard.

Answer (score -3):

Hugs is a version of Haskell that started out on Linux and is therefore better optimised for it.